# Merging multiple queries preferentially

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to be able to merge two sorted queries, and merge them, preferring things in the first query (i.e. except for duplicates, everything in the first query is favored over everything in the second query). Better still, I'd be able to do this with one query, rather than multiple queries (although I'm not too picky).

For example, if the first query returned:

```
"Apple"
"Bat"
"Dolphin"
```

And the second one returned:

```
"Cat"
"Dolphin"
"Elephant"
```

I'd want the results to look like this:

```
"Apple"
"Bat"
"Dolphin"
"Cat"
"Elephant"
```

If it helps, I'm trying to implement a search feature, but want it to be flexible. The first query may be things that exactly match, the second may be things that begin with the query string, and a third, for example, may be things that contain the query string anywhere.
Each query is a superset of the previous query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve by using `UNION` to select values from all tables and giving each table an order value.

```
select distinct Word
from
(
  select Word, 1 as WordOrder from table1
  union
  select Word, 2 as WordOrder from table2
) X
order by WordOrder
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23f5b/1)

Comment: This wouldn't be a huge issue if these were all being selected from the same table, right?

Comment: It doesn't matter. See my updated SQL Fiddle to who how it works from one table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do a union select. You can use different conditions in where for each query and merge the result:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE ...

UNION 
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE ...
```

You can even merge the result from different tables, if the columns in result are the same in all querys:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE ...

UNION 
SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE ...
```